# Need java test cases to test MarkSweep Garbage collector

Tags: java

Can anyone provide me test cases in java in which objects are being incrementally created so that i can use those to test my MarkSweep garbage collection code.

Answer (score 1):

The Jikes RVM open source project has a complete suite of regression tests.  You might find some ideas there.

http://jikesrvm.org/Regression+Tests

Their page about mark/sweep collection is here:

http://jikesrvm.org/Building+a+Mark-sweep+Collector